# HttpApplication and the current page

Tags: asp.net, path, httprequest, httpapplication

As we all know the HttpApplication object holds objects regarding the requested page (HttpRequest) and the page where we are supposed to be redirected (HttpResponse); I need to get the url of the page which requested the page; how could I get it from the HttpApplication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check the url referrer header like so:

`string MyReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();`

This value is set by the browser however - so can't exactly be trusted from a security viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HttpRequest.UrlReferrer property see - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx